# ProcessStartInfo not recognising command inside .sh file

Tags: ubuntu, process, monodevelop, asp.net-core, processstartinfo

I'm trying to run the following commands from a file called teste.sh

```
kpm restore
k web
```

They run just fine when I open the terminal cd to the correct folder and do "sh teste.sh", but when i try to run the following on monodevelop:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace terminalcommandteste
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            StartWebServer ();
        }

        public static void StartWebServer ()
        {
            string command = "sh";
            //string argss = "/home/daniel/Downloads/HelloWorldVNext-master/src/hellomvc/teste.sh";
            string dir = "/home/daniel/Downloads/HelloWorldVNext-master/src/hellomvc/";
            string argss = "teste.sh";

            ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ();
            procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procInfo.FileName = command;
            procInfo.Arguments = argss;
            procInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;
            Process.Start (procInfo);
        }
    }

}
```

The response on the terminal is:

```
teste.sh: 1: teste.sh: kpm: not found
teste.sh: 2: teste.sh: k: not found

Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix my issue thanks to **alexkoeplinger**, **Alxandr.me** and **Yantr.io** in the https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/AspNetvNext chat

changed the project to

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace terminalcommandteste
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            StartWebServer ();
        }

        public static void StartWebServer ()
        {
            string command = "/bin/bash";
            //string argss = "/home/daniel/Downloads/HelloWorldVNext-master/src/hellomvc/teste.sh";
            string dir = "/home/daniel/Downloads/HelloWorldVNext-master/src/hellomvc/";
            string argss = "teste.sh";

            ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ();
            procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procInfo.FileName = command;
            procInfo.Arguments = argss;
            procInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;
            Process.Start (procInfo).WaitForExit();
        }
    }

}
```

and the teste.sh to

```
#!/bin/bash
source "/home/daniel/.kre/kvm/kvm.sh"

kpm restore
k web
```